# Prepend value to existing data attribute value without replacing

Tags: jquery, html

I have script like below ,

```
$('.button-book-it').attr('data-book-check', new_date);
```

and my html button is below,

```
<input type="submit" id="schedule_btn1" data-id="schedule_form1" data-book-check="Monday, May 16, 2016" name="submit" data-hidden-value="11:30:00" data-hidden-value-end="12:00:00" data-value="7:30 AM EST" value="Book it" class="button-book-it book_link" disabled=""></input>
```

I need to prepend new_date value to data-book-check attribute without replacing current value 7:30 AM EST. Please note that it is in data attribute.

Comment: can you show what it looks like and how it would look like after adding new additional value?

Comment: @guradio  it replaces current value

Comment: pls udpate the OP not in comment

Comment: from the code above it will definitely replace you need to `$('.button-book-it').attr('data-book-check')+new_date` something like this if you want to use the old plus new value

Comment: something like `$('.button-book-it').attr('data-book-check', $('.button-book-it').attr('data-book-check')+new_date);   `

Comment: Just use normal string append operation using `+`.  - `$('.button-book-it').data('book-check', new_date + $('.button-book-it').data('book-check'))`

Comment: `7:30 AM EST` is the value of `data-value` not `data-book-check`.. Which attribute's value you want to replace?

Comment: @guradio  its working but how can I put new_date before existing value ( prepend ) ?

Comment: exchange the position `$('.button-book-it').attr('data-book-check', new_date+$('.button-book-it').attr('data-book-check'));` @doe_noikov

Comment: Thanks :) and for all thanks

Comment: @doe_noikov i posted it as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button-book-it').attr('data-book-check', new_date+$('.button-book-it').attr('data-book-check'));
```

Use the new data attributes and the old attribute when setting the value. use `+` to combine them

Answer (score 0):

This will get it done. Use code inspector to view changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-book-it").click(function(){
      
      var new_date = "11:30:00";
       
      var old_date =  $(this).attr('data-book-check');
                                               
      $(this).attr('data-book-check', new_date + " " + old_date );      
    
      
    });
   
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="schedule_btn1" data-id="schedule_form1" data-book-check="7:30 AM EST" name="submit" data-hidden-value="11:30:00"  data-hidden-value-end="12:00:00" data-value="7:30 AM EST" value="Book it" class="button-book-it book_link">
```